# The value of "ID" column is "0" when use db.Create and db.FirstOrCreate to save data into database

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using "do.FirstOrCreate" to check my data and I want the data been created if it not exist in my table, everything works well except the "ID" not generated (the value of "ID" column is 0).

here are my codes:

`domain object`

[image]

`codes calling db.FirstOrCreate`

[image]

here is the data inserted into my user table:

[image]

the gorm version is : 1.9.1

Comment: ID table on database already use autoincrement?

Comment: @MochLutfi no, the ID column is not auto increment. here is the DDL:
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL ,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL ,
  `username` varchar(100)  ,
  `email` varchar(100)  ,
  `mobile` varchar(20)  ,
  `nickname` varchar(100)  ,
  `avatar` varchar(255)  ,
  `password` varchar(40)  ,
  `salt` varchar(40)  ,
  `lang` varchar(40)  ,
  `register_from` varchar(40) ,
  `status` varchar(40) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: Can you try adding `ID unit` into the model exclusively and check if the ID is being populated with Non-Zero values.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, as your suggestion, i move the "id" into my user model: type User struct {
 ID           uint              `gorm:"id;primary_key;type:bigint(20);"`
}. but there is nothing changed. the "ID" column also be 0

Comment: Can you change your definition to look like -> `ID int `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"``. Also, I don't see this as an issue with `gorm`. Can you also update your question with the `create` code.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, yes you are right. when change the "id" column definition to "auto_increment", the issue solved. i ever think the "id" column don't need to be "auto increment", the gorm can handle the id value properly .. it's my fault. thanks ~

Comment: Please [do not include images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)! They are hard to read. Instead, copy and paste your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your definition to look like this

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  ID int `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  ..
  ..
}
```